# Optimal partitioning of a planar graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, spectral-graph-theory

Consider a planar graph, where each node is associated with a weight. I would like to partition the graph such that the sum of the node weights in each group satisfy a minimum requirement. However, I would also like as much 'resolution' as possible - that is, I want to maximize the number of groups (minimize the number of nodes per group). Internal edges should be rewarded, to avoid long 'daisy chains' of nodes.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can compute an (approximately) optimal solution? My instinct is to approach this using Monte Carlo, but I'm not sure how I would implement it here.

Thanks in advance for any insights or comments you might have!

Comment: Where do the edges feature in the optimisation? I see you have "Internal edges should be rewarded, to avoid long 'daisy chains' of nodes." Can you elaborate?

Comment: I suspect the goal is to maximize "internal edges" in the sense of intragroup edges.  Of course another approach would be penalties for intergroup edges.

Comment: You've got two different optimization targets: the number of groups, and the number of edges per group. Until you tell us how to balance these two goals, we won't be able to make any reasonable suggestions. Also: how does planarity figure in here? Does the partition have to be a reticulation of the plane in which every partition is entirely contained within a cell? Or could I partition a maximally triangulated regular hexagon into three "groups", each consisting of two antipodal vertices?

Comment: This seems to be a cross-post of a [question at SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/optimal-partitioning-of-a-graph) and a reasonable answer given there.  The "answer" below reads like a comment by the OP posting from another account.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback - I'm new to stack exchange, so I can't comment yet, so I'll try submitting my response here.

@John Hughes, perhaps an explanation of the real-world problem would be more useful. The graph is planar simply because it represents a geographic map. Each vertex is a region of the USA; an edge exists between vertices if those regions share a border. The count of certain areas is less than 50 - in that case, contiguous regions must be grouped together to meet this requirement. To include information from every area I could of course form one enormous group, but on the other hand, I would like as much spatial resolution as possible. An acceptable partitioning would compromise between resolution and including as many vertices as possible.

Please forgive my lack of mathematical maturity - this problem is far from my area of expertise. It's a fun problem to think about, though!